# ClusterManager isn't redrawing Markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use `ClusterManager` in order to cluster my `CustomMapMarker`s, but when the marker data changes and I call `mClusterManager.cluster()`, the pin positions don't change.

Code:

Map Update Method

```
void updateMap() {
  mClusterManager.clearItems();
  mClusterManager.addItem(data.getMarker(id));
  mClusterManager.cluster();
}
```

Marker Update Method

```
CustomMarker processMarkerUpdate(JSONObject json) {
  CustomMarker cm = new CustomMarker(json.optDouble("latitude", 0.0), json.optDouble("longitude",0.0));

  if (json.has("id")) {
    cm.setUid(json.getString("id"));
  } else {
    //If this happens, we stop processing.
    throw new InvalidCMException();
  }

  cm.setLabel(json.optString("label", ""));

  return cm;
}
```

I've triple checked the coordinates and they are changed in the object, but the marker does not move on the map.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Just a comment, shouldn’t it be mClusterManager.addItem() rather than add() ?

Comment: @mvai You are correct, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had overridden my `Marker` implementation's `hashCode()` method, which was apparently causing the usual replacing functionality of hash-type collections to act wonky. My solution was to remove my custom implementation and work around the need for it.