# ClusterManager.clearItems() does not clear items

Tags: android, google-maps

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [ClusterManager isn't redrawing Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022080/clustermanager-isnt-redrawing-markers)

I've done some investigation and found something interesting. `ClusterManager.clearItems()` does not always clear items.

After adding one marker to the `ClusterManager` I run this block:

```
mClusterManager.clearItems();
Log.d(TAG, "Marker list is empty: " + String.valueOf(mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers().isEmpty()));
for (Marker m : mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers()) {
    Log.d(TAG, m.getId() + "| "  + m.getPosition());
}
```

Which provides the following output:

```
02-03 12:30:52.953 14328-14328/com.app.mobile D/app:MapsActivity: Marker list is empty: false
02-03 12:30:52.954 14328-14328/com.app.mobile D/app:MapsActivity: m7| lat/lng: (33.2980945,-111.953964)
```

It is never empty in spite of clear being called. What's going on here?

If it never empties, is adding an updated `m7 Marker` to the `ClusterManager` ignored?

[Link to Google's implementation of `clearItems()`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java)

Comment: You can try to update the api with an `updateItem(Item)` method. It's the same instance of the added item but has updated attributes. Please see this link for [reference](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/168).

Comment: @abielita The code in your link is precisely the code in my original question linked at the top of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up discovering that my override implementation of `hashCode()` in my implementation of `Marker` was causing the usual replace/remove/clear functionality to malfunction.

My solution was to remove my implementation of `hashCode()` and work around my need for a custom hash solution.

Answer (score 14):

Call the cluster() function just after clearItems()

Comment: doesn't make any difference on my side